# Diophantine equation (number theory)

Tags: number-theory

The task is: Find the date of birth if the sum of the number that represents the day of birth multiplied by 12 and the month of birth multiplied by 21 is 374. Solve the problem with Diophantine equation.

This is my solution:
**x** - day of birth
**y** - month of birth

So, we have: **$12x+31y=374$** where **$a=12$**, **$b=31$** and **$c=374$**
**$(a;b)=(12;31)=1$** and **$1|375$**

**$1 = 12α+31β$**

**$31 = 2*12+7 => 12=1*7+5 => 7 = 1*5+2 => 5=2*2+1 $**

Therefore: **$1 = 10*12-4*31$**

so -> **$α=10,   β=-4$**

So one of the particular solutions is:
$x=(α*c)/(a;b)=3740$ and **$y=(β*c)/(a;b)=-1496$**

But those solutions can't be a date of birth and now my question is, can I just say that because this particular solution is not the one we need in this case we say that **$x=26$** and then we calculate **$y=2$** or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Is the month multiplied by $21$ or $31$?

Comment: x - day of birth y - month of birth -> 12*day of birth + 31*month of birth :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a mistake somewhere early, you actually have: 
$$ 1= 12(13) + 31(-5)$$
Then $ 374= 12\cdot 4862 + 31 \cdot (-1870)$
So we get that $374 = 12\cdot (4862-31n) + 31 \cdot (12n-1870)$  for any $n\in \Bbb{Z}$
Letting $n=156$ we see that $x=26, y=2$ and we're done!

Comment: But if $x=8$ and $y=9$ it will be $12*8+31*9=375$ not $374$

Comment: And thank you for pointing the mistake :)

Comment: Omg woops, I did it all with 375!!!

Comment: Edited to fix that mistake

Comment: And I got the same result so this is it! :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The *extended Extended algorithm*  for $12$ and $31$ yield $12\cdot 13-31\cdot 5=1$, hence all solutions for a *Bézout's identity* $\;12x+31y=1$ are given by
$$x=13+31k,\quad y=-5-12k\qquad(k\in\mathbf Z),$$
and the solutions for your equation are 
$$x=374\cdot12\cdot13+31k,\quad y=-374\cdot31\cdot5-12k\qquad(k\in\mathbf Z),$$
so all one has to do is determining all values of $k$, if any, such that $x$ and $y$ are compatible with their interpretation as ‘day of the month’ and ‘month’.